# How to create a working Executable file (.exe) from a C code

Tags: c, executable

I have a C code created in Plato3. I want to create an exe file so I can share it with others.
Can someone please tell me how is this possible ?

I have tried sending the exe file that is created when normally compiled, but it crashes every time in runs on computers other than mine ...

Please help,
Thanks :)

[EDIT]

Program running on windows xp or vista .. same error :
Compiler used : SilverFrost (Fortran/C/C++) Development Studio (Plato3)

> This application has failed to start
>   because `salflibc.dll` was not found,
>   reinstalling the application may fix
>   this problem

Comment: You should provide more information about what kind of crash you're seeing, what operating systems it's running on, etc. etc.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to use http://www.ceet.niu.edu/faculty/kim/mee380/programs/SilverFrost.htm aka http://www.silverfrost.com/16/plato3.aspx.

Comment: THis is what was given to me in the course, I cant change it until I finish the course. So you're telling me that I cant create an exe file ? (btw why did you delete the error msg ? )

Comment: There is something wrong with it if it says "reinstalling…may fix this problem," that we can't fix. Sorry about the edit, I restored it… Stack Overflow didn't even tell me you had edited at the same time as me.

Comment: Perhaps its because of the weak compiler used ... Should get Visual Studio...

Comment: This thread http://forums.silverfrost.com/viewtopic.php?t=1425 suggests that Silverfrost is indeed its own C++ compiler, which isn't even advertised, rather than a Visual Studio frontend. This program is virtually unknown. My advice to you is to try and find another class to take… something is wrong if they cannot configure your environment, and if they choose a compiler intended only as support for another product.

Comment: Ah, but this http://www.silverfrost.com/13/ftn95/ftn95_fortran_95_for_windows_features.aspx#cinterop suggests the C++ backend is indeed Visual C++. So, if you have access to MSVC, just use that instead.

Comment: Ah, no, VS is usable as a *frontend*. http://forums.silverfrost.com/viewtopic.php?t=1590 makes it clear that SF is its own, highly inferior, C++ compiler.

Comment: Thanks for replying guys .. I get it, I need to change my compiler !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`salflibc.dll` is a library installed by the compiler on your development machine.

- `salf` = Salford C Compiler, the obscure compiler included in Silverfrost
- `libc` = C-language runtime  support library, necessary for the basic functionality of any program
- `.dll` = dynamically-linked library, i.e. a separate file from your `.exe` file

You might look for a compiler option that looks like "statically link runtime library;" this might eliminate the DLL dependency. However, if the compiler were capable of doing that, one would expect it to be the default, if not the only way.

However, I recall from the olden days of Classic Mac OS that sometimes DLL runtime libraries were used, the benefit being upgradability. *Sometimes* is a key word, though. (I suppose when the compiler vendor is the OS vendor, as with MSVC or Apple GCC, it is the norm, though.)

Another trick from that environment was to put the DLL in question in the application's directory and distribute it with the app. Typically runtime DLLs are licensed for free redistribution.

Answer (score 1):

At the very least you have to make sure that the executable is running on the same architecture/operating system that it was compiled on.

Additionally, you need to make sure that any third party, or system libraries that are needed are available on the other systems too.

*update*

Based on the new information and error message you provide, it looks like you need to re-distribute the salflibc.dll

I would agree with other commenter's and suggest a different platform for development that is more mainstream, or supported.

Comment: What if im sending it to a friend that has never used a programming software before ?

Comment: That is irrelevant.  It would help if we knew which operating system, compiler, etc. you were using, as well as an indication of what kind of code and application you were writing.

Comment: Already mentioned in question .. Operating system = vista and xp, compiler = Silverfrost Plato3